# Add columns based on another columns value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, list, column

I am trying to implement a Basic CRM in SharePoint. Although there are a lot of Add-Ins for SharePoint I want to do it by myself. So I made a sub-site and added some lists for the different modules like Companies, Contact, Leads, Projects.
So unfortunately our Contacts are assigned to the different Projects. So, if a contact is assigned to Project 1 and this project defines some contact-specific columns, those columns should be displayed/added tho the contacts-list, but only for this contact. Not for the others.

I think this is not possible but it's worth a question.

So if this is not possible I could create a contact-list for every project and made a search view to search all these lists across the projects.

Perhaps you have some advices for me.

Thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a list of all contacts and then have a lookup column that pertains to the project or projects he/she is on? Then you can filter in or out the contacts that the Project pertains to. The contact would have a lookup column called "Project" that would point back to the Project on hand--and let there be multiple selections.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each contact can only be assigned to one project, then one possiblity could be to use different content types based on the project the contact is assigned to.

Have a base Contact content type.
Then for each project create a Project X contact content type, which inherits from the base Contact content type and adds the fields needed for Project X.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was testing with different Content types and different relationships. Thinking, I'm done tomorrow. I will Reply and post a solution (hopefully). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at how Microsoft does it; there is a new App in the Store

https://store.office.com/office-365-project-portfolio-dashboard-WA104380116.aspx?assetid=WA104380116&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

**I have not seen this app... so I am not saying it has any value!!**

[image]